# Integrability of the limit of convergent integrable sequence in measure

Tags: real-analysis

If $|f_n| \leq g \in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure, is it true that $f \in L^1$?

The Dominated Convergence Theorem can be applied if $f_n \to f$ a.e but I am not sure for convergence in measure.

Comment: Convergence in measure implies convergence along a subsequence, and then Fatou's lemma can be used to show that $f \in L^1$